# c# method multi run

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm making a few requests in the method. How can I run the same method more than once to make it work faster? The codes in the method need to be completed. Let the 1st method run 3 times at the same time. After completion, let the 2nd method run.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Codes();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void Codes()
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            SomeRequests();
        }
        OtherMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean execute `SomeRequests` in parallel to potentially leverage multi cores  ? I so it depends what it is actually doing and wether it can be parallelized.

Comment: It contains a GET request and several POST requests using leaf.xNet

Comment: If they are independent, you can use e.g. [Parallel.For](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=net-7.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the iterations executing `SomeRequests()` are independent (i.e. can be executed in parallel taking into account what it actually does),
you can modify this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    SomeRequests();
}
```

To use [`Paralle.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netframework-4.6.1) in order to parallelize it:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks; // For Parallel.For
//...
Parallel.For(0, 3, i => {
    SomeRequests();
});
```

Note that this does not guarantee the actual level of parallelism which is dependent on your system (available cores etc.).